# "I was in London, aged 14" sounds like it's saying that London was 14…?

Tags: grammar

The guy who wrote that sentence was indicating that HE was 14 at the time of his story, but it seems to me that his grammar is incorrect, and is in fact saying that LONDON was 14… can someone please explain if the grammar used here is right or wrong? Thank you!

To clarify, I believe that this is INCORRECT GRAMMAR, and I'm hoping someone can explain WHY it is incorrect with some sort of grammatical rule. I don't CARE whether or not we can understand what this person meant, I'm looking for a *grammatical rule*!

Comment: I can't imagine many people would be confused by this particular example. People rarely refer to towns or cities by their age.

Comment: Idiomatic would be "at age 14" or "when I was 14"   *aged 14* sounds like something from an APB sent out by the police. *Suspect, aged 14, is presumed armed and dangerous.*

Comment: What's the full sentence, what's the source? It is quite terse/telegraphic style, so would be more appropriate in some situations than others. But there's no requirement on a writer to avoid unlikely interpretations or prevent every possible ambiguity: "The door was [green](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green), by which I mean the colour and I'm not saying that it was jealous of anything, or a new and inexperienced door, or one concerned with environmental issues."

Comment: In all languages, there are occasions when common sense needs to be applied.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the context makes the answer obvious.

Comment: @Goingcrazy Grammar is correct, context and common sense is needed to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Going Crazy - usually, people and animals are 'aged _NUMBER_'; cities are '_NUMBER_ years old', so the 'aged 14'is understood to refer to the person 'I'.

Comment: Compare "I was working in a restaurant, waiting tables". Clearly the restaurant wasn't waiting tables. Do you consider this INCORRECT GRAMMAR? If not, why is OK and your example is wrong?

Comment: @user81561: Just because it's obvious what thew cited text means doesn't imply the answer to the OP's question is obvious. OP says *I'm looking for a grammatical rule*, to which the only sensible "answer" is ***There is no such rule*** (but there's no guarantee the OP will actually *accept* that answer! :)

Comment: I initially voted to close this question, because the OP appears argumentative, but I have retracted the vote. Nevertheless I'd remind the poster to be courteous, and give general advice that they avoid writing in CAPITALS, as it is often interpreted as shouting and/or aggressive.

Answer (score 4):

Some might say that there is an unfortunate misplaced modifier, but

- *I, aged 14, was in London*

sounds worse.

- *I was in London, aged 14*

is not so much ungrammatical as rather unnatural-sounding. The fact that

- *The promising apprentice Tom Cartright, aged 14, was in London*

sounds so much better strongly indicates that this is a style issue; 'padding' often makes sentences with identical or near identical structures more natural-sounding.

Look, for instance, at

- ?*Very sad, the boy sat on the grassy hill*

and

- *Profoundly unhappy, the boy sat on the grassy hill*

The longer absolute parenthetical sounds far more natural.

There is also the fact that being in London and being 14 at the time might sound better if given more equal emphasis:

- *I was fourteen, and I was in London*
- *I was a fourteen-year-old, and I was in London*
- *I was a fourteen-year-old in London!*

Note how

- ?*I, in London, was fourteen*

while again grammatical (and appropriate context could make this quite acceptable) does again not sound natural without such context

- *John was still finding Leeds daunting after spending all his teenage years in the city; I, in London, was fourteen*.

Answer (score 0):

@EdwinAshworth's answer is good, but I thought I'd provide a short alternative.

How we express ourselves in language often includes unintentional ambiguities, even in entirely grammatically correct sentences. Those ambiguities are usually cleared up by context. Such is the case with your example.

Nevertheless, grammatical sentences that include ambiguities or double meanings are a common source of unintentional comedy. But at worst these are examples of poor writing, not ungrammatical writing.

I remember reading about an inscription on a gravestone that went something like this:

Erected to the memory of

John Smith, Aged 40

Drowned in Lake Windemere

By a few of his affectionate friends